# Why the value area in debugging in Chrome is too small?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging

When I am debugging JS code in Chrome and what to check the variable value, I can't see it anymore (before it was fine, but something changed recently).

So each time I have to add this variable to Watch list. It is very inconvenient.

[image]

I want to see the full value in this fully opened box each time I hover over it. **Like it was working before.**

**Chrome version:** 51.0.2704.103

**OS:** Windows 10 Pro

Comment: Tip: just hit variable (object) name in console, it will print it's value...

Comment: What version of chrome are you running? What OS?

Comment: Chrome version: 51.0.2704.103
OS: Windows 10 Pro

Comment: I had the same issue.  Seems to be fixed in my version: 52.0.2743.116 m

Comment: Just updated to Version 52.0.2743.116 m and restarted Chrome - same issue. =(((

Comment: Any other suggestion?

Comment: Same issue here, Win7 + 54.0.2840.99 m, but I've had it for quite a while.